# ArrayList removes only content and not element

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've written a code similar to this:

```
ArrayList<String> someArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
....
....
inserts elements into someArrayList
....
....
int location = 4;
someArrayList.remove(location);
```

It has a size of 5, when I run through this, it removes the content at position 4, but the size doesn't change, it keeps being of 5 and when I get to the 4th element it is shown as empty.

Should I do something else to erase position 4 completely or what?

**EDIT**

Logcat before removing:

```
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): [1, 2, 3, 4]
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): [1396850896.089319.jpg
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): , 1396850896.47272.png
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): , 1396850897.830785.jpg
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): , 1396850895.729823.jpg
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): ]
```

Logcat exactly after doing a someArrayList.remove(location);

```
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): [1, 2, 3, 4]
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): [1396850896.089319.jpg
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): , 1396850896.47272.png
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): , 1396850895.729823.jpg
04-14 15:03:41.790: W/System.err(22971): ]
```

i do this:

```
// get all ids

    curFileName.moveToFirst();
    while(!curFileName.isAfterLast()) {
        ids.add(curFileName.getString(curFileName.getColumnIndex("id")));
        curFileName.moveToNext();
    }

    // get all filenames

    curFileName.moveToFirst();
    while(!curFileName.isAfterLast()) {
        filenames.add(curFileName.getString(curFileName.getColumnIndex("filename")));
        curFileName.moveToNext();
    }
```

and then after doing some work:

```
filenames.remove(location); // location is calculated when the work is being done
```

Comment: Could you show a complete program that outputs size before and after the remove operation. Also what do you mean by "empty", null?

Comment: No. It should not. Show us complete code.

Comment: Please post minimal executable code reproducing your problem.

Comment: Seems that there are only 4 elements before removing, therefore no index `4`.

Comment: As I can see you only have 4 elements in your list so you cant call someArrayList.remove(4); since list doesnt have 5th Element it should throw IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Please post your add operations too.

Comment: We need more complete code to see where the problem comes from. I know there might be much code, but try to post something minimal but complete.

Comment: those are exactly the only operations i do with the arraylist, aside from some filenames.get() and filenames.size()

Comment: You've not posted how `location` is calculated, nor how you print those logcats, nor what you mean by "shown as empty", nor how you know that the size is still 5.

Comment: @DomeWTF Do you also print filenames.size() before the remove? I think your problem here is that the list isn't the size you think it is

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
someArrayList.trimToSize();
```

After removing the element.

Comment: `arrayList.trimToSize();` only trims the **capacity** to the current size, it doesn't affect the size itself (and probably has very few uses